# Web-Services Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

now i have a button called activities that when u press on it it gets from database activity name and which class in school did this activity and the images of this activity so am doing something like in server side java part am getting all activites of class a in an arraylist and of class b in an arraylist and class c in an arraylist then i added these 3 arraylists in an arraylist!..and this big arraylist i converted to json but when i receive it in android part there is an error :(

**Server side:**

```
public static String constructJS(String tag, boolean status,ArrayList<ArrayList<Activities>> f) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
            for(int i=0;i<f.size();i++){
            obj.put("tag", tag);
            obj.put("status", new Boolean(status));
            String json = new Gson().toJson(f);
            obj.put("data",json);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return obj.toString(); 
}
```

and here when i print the obj.toString i get the json!!

in android part when i receive it :

**Client Side**

```
     public void onSuccess(String response) {
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            //    prgDialog.hide();
            try {
                // JSON Object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true
                if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                    String j = obj.get("data").toString();


                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(j);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject busName = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String busPhone = busName.getString("activityname");
                        String busPhon = busName.getString("activityclass");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), busPhon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

i get the error when i debug in this line : JSONArray data = new JSONArray(j);

Comment: "the error" meaning?

Comment: Have you taken a look onto what the converted json String looks like?

Comment: Show your json string if you can

Comment: {"tag":"login","status":true,"data":"[[{\"activityname\":\"Connect-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"a\"},{\"activityname\":\"Connect-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"c\"},{\"activityname\":\"Drawing-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"a\"},{\"activityname\":\"Connect-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"c\"},{\"activityname\":\"Connect-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"a\"},{\"activityname\":\"Drawing-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"b\"},{\"activityname\":\"Connect-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"a\"},{\"activityname\":\"Connect-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"a\"},{\"activityname\":\"Drawing-Day\",\"activityclass\":\"b\"}]]"}

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to create object of jsonarray
i.e. JSONArray data = new JSONArray(j);
just assign the jsonarray value to JSONArray reference

```
public void onSuccess(String response) {
        // Hide Progress Dialog
        //    prgDialog.hide();
        try {
            // JSON Object
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true
            if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                //String j = obj.get("data").toString();
                // dont't need to do this

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //JSONArray data = new JSONArray(j);
                JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data"); //add this line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject busName = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String busPhone = busName.getString("activityname");
                    String busPhon = busName.getString("activityclass");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), busPhon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```